# Cannot redeclare class Stringy\Stringy

Tags: php, laravel

> Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class Stringy\Stringy in D:\work\bookstrore-laravel\vendor\danielstjules\stringy\src\Stringy.php on line 5

i have this error when run EVERY laravel project.i'm using phpstorm 9.0. 
and i can run it by php artisan serve in the project directory. i'm new with this and i really don't know why it's can't run on phpstorm

Comment: That error reported by PHP and not PhpStorm. This means that you have included/required that file more than once.

Comment: i'm only change the computer. this project run with no error on my laptop. But with this computer that's error appear in every laravel project i run (include new laravel project).